# Error: `raise ValueError( ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'Date'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using a `.csv` with two columns. The first has dates and the second has temperatures. I would like to plot it with dates on the x-axis and temperatures on the y-axis.

I used this command:

```
dataset = pandas.read_csv('/home/UbuntuUser/Desktop/mesurements.csv', 
          usecols=[1], engine='python', skipfooter=3, index_col=['Date'],
          parse_dates=['Date'])
```

but I got the error:

```
Error: raise ValueError(
ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'Date'
```

Any ideas why? From searching, I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953673/pandas-read-csv-parse-dates-true-missing-out-date-column), that does not help me.

Update:

Part of the code is from here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
import pandas as pd

# Import csv file
df = pd.read_csv('rsam_2016-17_fft_test.csv', index_col=['DateTime'], parse_dates=['DateTime'])
print(df.head())

#plot data
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
df.plot(linestyle = '', marker = '*', color='r')
plt.savefig('rsam_2016_2017_snippetforfft.jpg')
plt.show()
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622933/python-performing-fft-on-csv-values-using-scipy-documentation)

Comment: Does your dataset contain a column with the name 'Date'?

Comment: Yes! I have just checked it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the `Date` column as `index` the same time you are parsing it. Once it is set as the index, this is not a column anymore (but the index) so the `parse_dates` does not find any column name Date

Try this:

```
dataset = pandas.read_csv('/home/UbuntuUser/Desktop/mesurements.csv', 
          engine='python', skipfooter=3,
          parse_dates=['Date'])

dataset.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
```

Comment: I get this error, I don't know why! `File "/home/UbuntuUser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/base_parser.py", line 276, in _validate_parse_dates_presence
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'Date'`

Comment: might be for the usecols parameter, you are telling only to use the second feature, so remove it and try again

Comment: Indeed, it works!!!! Thanks!! But how can I choose between columns, if I have for instance 3 columns , the 1st is the Date, the 2nd is the temperature, the 3rd is the humidity. And I need to make two different plots (not in the same plot). One plot with the Dates and temperature and another plot with Dates and humidity?

Comment: I would read all the features (no usecols parameter on read CSV), and then with pandas, select the columns I need to plot.